# AWS SAM deploy failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-sam

I was testing the AWS SAM functionality and encountered an issue.

If by manually delete a resource that was originally created by the SAM template, then subsequent SAM deployment will fail. I do understand that deleting resource manually that was created by SAM is not a good practice. But this was just a test only

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPM9K.png)

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`AWS SAM` uses `Cloudformation` underneath to create various resources.

[How do I update an AWS CloudFormation stack that's failing because of a resource that I manually deleted?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/failing-stack-updates-deleted/)

> If you delete a resource from an AWS CloudFormation stack, then you must remove the resource from your AWS CloudFormation template. Otherwise, your stack fails to update, and you get an error message.

similar post : [Function not found after manually deleting a function in a SAM CloudFormation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184183/2246345)